# Add jquery event to joomla mainmenu module

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, joomla, joomla-extensions

I have a joomla site that loads the main menu module like this:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="topmenu"/>
```

This module load an  tag. I want to use jquery with that  tag.
The problem is that my jquery code doesn't work doing this:

```
$("menu")
```

It seems that the `<ul class"menu">` must be loaded before i use jquery, other way jquery doesn't find the class.

Any idea on how can i use jquery with my mainmenu module?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // $('menu') is available here
});
```